# Calling git.init() when repository already exists

Tags: jgit

I am using the following snippet of code to initialize the git repository:

```
try (Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(gitFilename).call()) {
    log.info("Created repository: " + git.getRepository().getDirectory());
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What happens when the repository is already created and I call `git.init()` on it?

Thanks! Ana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to work for me:

```
//initialize git repository
        String gitDirectory = getGitRepoDirectory();
        File gitFilename = new File(gitDirectory);
        try (Git git = Git.open(gitFilename)){
            log.info("Git repo " + gitDirectory + " exists!");;
        } catch (RepositoryNotFoundException e) {
            log.info("Initialising " + gitDirectory + " as a git repo for backup purposes");
            try {
                Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(gitFilename).call();

                } catch (GitAPIException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```